# Logback Groovy Configuration slow

Tags: java, logging, groovy, configuration, logback

I've been using Logback Groovy configuration, and now I found out that it's the cause of very slow startup. A `HelloWorld` "application" needs about one second. I didn't notice the slowdown earlier in the context of web server, but now when I often need to run some rather simple tools, it's unacceptable.

*Q1: I still can't believe it, as my configuration file is small and one second is huge, so can someone confirm it?*

I can imagine to easily rewrite everything but one part back to XML. The problematic part is my own filter and its two methods like

```
public class MyLogbackFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {
    public MyLogbackFilter accept(String prefix, Level level) {...}
    public MyLogbackFilter accept(String prefix, Level level) {...}
   ...
}
```

configured via something like

```
filter = new MyLogbackFilter()
    .accept("com.example.pck1.Class1", TRACE)
    .accept("com.example.pck1.Class2", TRACE)
    .deny("com.example.pck1", TRACE)
    .accept("", WARNING)
    .deny("", INFO);
```

The rules get evaluated top-down, e.g., everything from `com.example.pck1.Class1` at level `TRACE` or higher gets accepted, no matter what's specified later.

*Q2: Can I somehow make logback read a configuration file like*

```
A com.example.pck1.Class1 TRACE
A com.example.pck1.Class2 TRACE
D com.example.pck1 TRACE
A * WARNING
D * INFO
```

and feed it to my class? The interpretation is then peanuts.

Answer (score 0):

Sincerely, i never know you can make appenders by class, BUT You can just add an xml config file to your  project, and the logback libraries tries to locate the xml in the classpath (usually, in maven you put the xml in the resources file).

The file can be like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <configuration>
        
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
          <file>/usr/java/logs/floresTrace.log</file>
            
           <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
              <fileNamePattern>/path/to/file/myfile.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
              <minIndex>1</minIndex>
              <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
              <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
 
            <encoder>
              <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line]   %msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

      <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
 
    </appender>
    <!-- you can, however add loggers by package here-->
    <logger name="your.package.one" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="your.package.two" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="your.package.two" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
    
    <root level="debug">
       <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    </configuration>
```

So, as the comment says, you can add loggers by package. hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea what "adding loggers by package" at the top level does. Imagine, I want the FILE appender to write everything and the STDOUT appender to write only specified levels by package. Can I achieve this?